# PHP Fatal error: Maximum execution time exceeded when using "if" in nested loops

Tags: php, arrays, loops

The purpose of this will be to output the options for an HTML drop down box but first checking to make sure that the option about to be printed is not present in $picked_numbers.

When I run this through my local installation of WAMP server it times out: "Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded". The problem ceases when I remove the if statement.

Why does this not run properly?

```
<?php

$picked_numbers = array(3, 7, 9);
$num_count = 3;
$num_range = 15;


for ($x = 1; $x <= $num_range; $x++) {  

    $num_found = 0;             

    for ($y = 0; $y < $num_count; $y++) {

        if ($x = $picked_numbers[$y]) {
            $num_found = 1;
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to change your if statement to a compare values and not assign them! So change this:

```
if ($x = $picked_numbers[$y]) {
    $num_found = 1;
}
```

to this:

```
if ($x == $picked_numbers[$y]) {
    $num_found = 1;
}
```

Also if you use the count of the array i would recommend you to change it to this (So you don't have to change it manually if there are more values in the array):

```
$picked_numbers = array(3, 7, 9);
$num_count = count($picked_numbers );
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are constantly setting `$x` to some other value in your `if`.

Try `if ($x == $picked_numbers[$y]) {` (equality operator instead of assigment operator)

As a side note: `num_found` is only ever 0 or 1, so perhaps the name is misleading. You either want `$num_found = $num_found + 1` to get a count, or rename it to `$item_found` since it is a flag and not a count.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I found yours just as helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Rizier123 correctly pinpointed the issue, which arose due to a common coding error of mistakenly using the assignment operator instead of the equality operator.  You may wish to consider an alternative way to exclude the options that a user picked, as follows:

```
<?php
$options_picked = array( 3,7,9 );
$range = range( 1,15 );
$arrRes = array_values( array_diff( $range, $options_picked ) );
print_r( $arrRes );

// all of the options exclusive of the user's choice of 3,  7, and 9
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 4
    [3] => 5
    [4] => 6
    [5] => 8
    [6] => 10
    [7] => 11
    [8] => 12
    [9] => 13
    [10] => 14
    [11] => 15
)
```